# Событие ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged постоянно срабатывает без остановки как это предотвратить? C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

у меня есть событие, когда скролл доходит до конца, я гружу данные но надо это делать только один раз, и только когда ползунок дошел до конца, то есть в данной проблеме он грузит данные без остановки.

Comment: Код приведите в вопрос.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1209999/373567 что вы именно сделали, почле чего оно стало так себя вести? Ведь в приведенном ранее мной примере такого не воспроизводилось.

Comment: я не знаю,но оно начало баговать(((

Comment: Вот и я не знаю. Покажите код обработчика.

Comment: А можно [mcve]?

Comment: я нашел косяк, я поставил свойство CanContentScroll = true

Answer (score 0):

Введите переменную isLoading. Проверяйте перед началом загрузки и изменяйте перед самой загрузкой и окончанием.